# WooCommerce listen for shipping method changes on checkout

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have some additional javascript I'm looking to run on the WooCommerce checkout page when a user changes their shipping method. Currently, I'm using the following;

```
jQuery( document.body ).on( 'updated_checkout', function() {
    // Javascript here...
});
```

The problem with the above is that this event fires when users also change any of the checkout data including the address. I only want to run my javascript when the shipping method is updated at checkout. I can't see any event listeners or hooks for this.

Comment: Add a `change` event handler directly for the relevant select field then ...? Surely that will have an ID or class by which it can be identified.

Comment: @CBroe Yes thank you I'm not sure why I was looking to over complicated the issue. Much appreciate your answer.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks, @CBroe in the comments for pointing me in the right direction, I was looking to overcomplicate the problem. See my solution below;

This works with the default WooCommerce shipping classes;

```
jQuery(document.body).on( 'change', 'input.shipping_method', function() {
    // Javascript here...
});
```

Comment: This worked for me, others alternatives like jQuery(".shipping_method").change(function() {}) or jQuery('input[type=radio][name="shipping_method"]').on('change', function() {}) didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can add this action:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_checkout_form', 'your_function' );
function your_function( $available_gateways ) {
    wc_enqueue_js( ";
$('form.checkout').on('change', 'input[name^=\"shipping_method\"]', function () {
    const val = $(this).val();
    // you code here ...
});
" );
```